# Facebook opengraph - get latest 5 updated posts from Facebook group?

Tags: php, json, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible and how to get latest 5 **updated** posts from Facebook group wall?

When i run https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?access_token=MY_TOKEN&limit=5 im receiving latest 5 **published** posts.

In Facebook documentation Im unable to find if there is some URL parameter for getting latest updated posts..

Comment: What do you mean with "updated" posts?

Comment: Posts which are updated for example with new comments. Such posts (even if they are older) are above other posts (even if they are newer).

Comment: Is there a filed from the HTTP GET response that indicates the latest comment? Or latest update time of the object? I don t think that you can retrieve those posts, the way you want them directly.

Comment: Yes, there is, but problem is that in that scenario i would have to take a large number of posts, then sort them according to the latest update and then display latest five. IMO it ll be dead slow process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the FQL [stream table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=
  SELECT message, attachment, actor_id, created_time, updated_time FROM stream
    WHERE source_id = GROUP_ID ORDER BY updated_time DESC
```

Comment: Again dead end. Even if ORDER BY works but for some reason last commented post (which is on top of the wall) is skipped..

Comment: You can't guarantee that all visible posts will be returned by the API. Read this for more info: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Grr.. I hate that :) Anyway thanks for trying to help me man!